# Passing Anonymous Classes

Tags: java, interface, anonymous

This is a question for Java. I have an interface called `IMyObjectPredicate` which implements a single test method to apply to an input:

```java
public interface IMyObjectPredicate {
    boolean test(MyObject x);
}
```

What I would like is to be able to pass an instance of `IMyObjectPredicate` around between objects and have the `test` function update its references to variables to those of the new object it is being passed to. For instance, consider a class which makes use of this predicate:

```java
public class Tester {
    MyObject o;
    IMyObjectPredicate myTestFunction;
    int myThreshold;

    public Tester(/*stuff*/) {
        /*Code here which initialises the Tester instance and 'myThreshold'*/
        myTestFunction = new IMyObjectPredicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(MyObject o) {
                return (o.value() > myThreshold);
            }
        };
    }

    public boolean isGood() {
        return myTestFunction.test(o);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to perform a *deep clone* of the Tester object for reasons I won't go into here. But the idea is that the cloned instance of `Tester` should test the predicate against its *own* value of `myThreshold`, not reference the `myThreshold` of the first instance. But if I pass `myTestFunction` to a new instance of `Tester`, I guess it will still be referencing the `myThreshold` value of the first instance, instead of dynamically evaluating `myThreshold` based on the reference of the enclosing class.

How can I accomplish the passing of a `IMyObjectPredicate` object whose test function uses references to the fields of the *new object it is passed to*?

**Edit:**
A complicating factor is that, in general, it will not be possible to reconstruct `myTestFunction` solely from the fields within a `Tester` object. `myTestFunction` may be overwritten by other parts of the program in a way that does not correlate with the other fields of `Tester`. I can sacrifice this functionality if need be, but I would rather not for the sake of elegance.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be possible.  But if it's in the constructor you can just create a new predicate.

Comment: @LouisWasserman In general, `myTestFunction` will be altered during the course of the program. I want to be able to copy it on demand as needed.

Comment: Your anonymous impl of `IMyObjectPredicate` has a no-arg `test()` method, but the interface requires it to take a `MyObject` argument ... ?

Comment: @MattMcHenry - Right you are, thank you. I've fixed it.

Comment: That, or maybe the right thing to do is alter IMyObjectPredicate to accept the Tester instance as an argument to sidestep the issue altogether.

Comment: @MattMcHenry - The `Tester` object in reality contains many instances of `MyObject`, and performs the test on all of them. Based on the outcomes, it does some other things with them.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - This is a good point, and I've considered this. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about things though, or whether there are alternative methods, so I thought I'd leave this question here and see what people think is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have an API to replace enclosed context of anonymous class.

The simplest solution I can see from your simplified example is to add threshold to the signature of test function. As I understand the threshold is going to be there anyway.

```
public interface IMyObjectPredicate {
    boolean test(MyObject x, int threshold);
}
```

---

Another approach would use some factory method that will create a predicate for provided threshold like

```
class PredicateFactory {
    IMyObjectPredicate thresholdPredicate(int threshold) {
        return new IMyObjectPredicate {
              //...
        }
    }
}
```

then you can pas this factory to object that will use it's own threshold to construct new instance of predicate

```
factory.thresholdPredicate(myThreshold);
```

Comment: Although this doesn't fully solve my issue, +1 for "Java does not have an API to replace enclosed context of anonymous class.". What I take away from this answer is that it isn't possible to pass a copy of `IMyObjectPredicate` in the way that I want unless I implement an explicit method to reconstruct the predicate from the fields of the new `Tester` object. This is a shame, since the `Tester` fields will not in general determine what the predicate should be. The predicate can be independently modified by other parts of the program.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier if `ImObjectPredicate` is an class that simply stores a reference to a predicate instead of an interface. If you're able to make that change, each predicate can store its own threshold, which solves the issue.

```
public IMyObjectPredicate {
    private int threshold;
    private Predicate<MyObject> pred;

    public int getThreshold() {
        return threshold;
    }

    public Predicate<MyObject> getPredicate() {
        return pred;
    }

    public IMObjectPredicate(int threshold, Predicate<MyObject> pred) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
        this.pred = pred;
    }

    public boolean test(MyObject o) {
        return pred.test(o);
    }
}

public class Tester {
    MyObject o;
    IMyObjectPredicate myTestFunction;
    IMyObjectPredicate myTestFunctionCopyWithDiffThreshold;
    int myThreshold;

    public Tester(/*stuff*/) {
        /*Code here which initialises the Tester instance and 'myThreshold'*/
        myTestFunction =
            new IMyObjectPredicate(myThreshold, o -> o.value() > getThreshold());
        myTestFunctionCopyWithDiffThreshold =
            new ImObjectPredicate(5, myTestFunction.getPredicate());
    }

    public boolean isGood() {
        return myTestFunction.test(o);
    }
}
```

This is the most sensible solution, as `ImObjectPredicate` *should* store its own threshold if that value uniquely refers to that `ImObjectPredicate`.

Comment: As per the update to my question, "ImObjectPredicate should store its own threshold if that value uniquely refers that that ImObjectPredicate" - unfortunately this is not the case. The fields of `Tester` **do not** uniquely determine the `IMyObjectPredicate`. I may have oversimplified the example a little.